# Submit button that has 3 submit buttons as droplist

Tags: html

ill be needing your help again. I'm trying to make a drop-list with the use of a submit button. for example, i have a submit button which has a value = CAR

then if i clicked the submit button CAR
the other 2 submit button display under the submit button of CAR.

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

see this link i hope this will help for you  jsfiddle.net/2KEVg/2/